# Matlab : How to disable validation and test data set in neural network

Tags: matlab

I need to train a `patternnet` neural network, using the entire data set in the training set and not for the validation or testing. I found two methods and they work very well in the command window but not in a script, returning errors.

method 1:

```
mynet.divideFcn = '';
```

method 2:

```
mynet.divideParam.trainRatio = 1;
mynet.divideParam.valRatio   = 0;
mynet.divideParam.testRatio  = 0;
```

and the code:

```
mynet=patternnet([]);

P=rand(10,1000);
T=rand(2,1000);

[mynet,tr]=train(mynet,P,T);
```

Using **Matlab R2012b** Windows XP 32bit

Comment: I'm by no means an expert of MATLAB neural networks implementation, but I have to ask you to specify **what errors** you get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use either of your methods in a script?

Putting together different parts of your question into a script as below does run without errors in 2015b...

```
mynet=patternnet([]);
% Edit mynet before training it
mynet.divideParam.trainRatio = 1;
mynet.divideParam.valRatio   = 0;
mynet.divideParam.testRatio  = 0;

P=rand(10,1000);
T=rand(2,1000);

[mynet,tr]=train(mynet,P,T);
```

---

**Edit:**

Your difficulty may be a subtle change in syntax using 2012b, so it's good to refer to the old documentation:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/nnet/ref/patternnet.html

Looks like you want to use [`dividetrain`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/nnet/ref/dividetrain.html), which will assign indices to your data, entirely for training.

> [trainInd,valInd,testInd] = dividetrain(Q,trainRatio,valRatio,testRatio) **assigns all targets to the training set and no targets to either the validation or test sets**.

```
Inputs:
Q = Number of targets to divide up.
Ratios = ratios of each data use type

Outputs:
trainInd = Training indices equal to 1:Q
valInd = Empty validation indices, []
testInd = Empty test indices, []
```

In your case, you could just create this manually, but it's worth knowing that these functions exist, for example if you want specific ratios then use [`divideint`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/nnet/ref/divideint.html).

Then try using

```
P=rand(10,1000);
T=rand(2,1000);

mynet=patternnet([]);
% Edit mynet before training it
mynet.divideParam.trainInd = trainInd; % 1:size(P,1)
mynet.divideParam.valInd   = valInd;   % []
mynet.divideParam.testInd  = testInd;  % []

[mynet,tr]=train(mynet,P,T);
```

Note: I don't have 2012b so cannot test this fully for you.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why you would answer "this doesn't work in a script" with the same commands in a script.

Comment: @excaza The OP hadn't shown their code structured like this, it might be that they'd found the methods, used them in the command line, and not run the script correctly? This code **does** work in a script...

Comment: It works for you. It explicitly does not work for the OP. There is not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: @excaza, valid opinion of yours, I've tried to answer it with the available information. If I were you I would be down-voting the question which you don't think is good enough, rather than its only answer...

Comment: Being the only answer does not make it a good one. If you do not have enough information to adequately answer the question then you shouldn't answer it.

Comment: @excaza Apologies for trying to post a helpful, tested answer

Comment: How is it helpful if the OP explicitly states that it doesn't work?

Comment: @excaza feud over, I've extended my answer.